# SugarORM Update

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

I'm using SugarORM to manage a friends list

- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
  <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="myfriends.db" />
  <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
  <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  ```
- Friend.java

  ```
  public class Friend extends SugarRecord{

  int recID;
  String name;
  String phone;

  public Friend(){}
  public Friend(int rec, String n, String p)
  {
      this.recID = rec;
      this.name = n;
      this.phone = p;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "[" + recID + ", " + name + ", " + phone + "]";
  }
  }
  ```
- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Insert"
  android:id="@+id/buttonInsert"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Delete"
  android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonInsert"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonInsert" />

  <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Update"
  android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDelete"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDelete" />

  <EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/editTextID"
  android:hint="Enter ID to update or delete"
  android:layout_below="@+id/buttonInsert"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/editTextName"
  android:hint="Enter new name"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editTextID"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="500dp"
  android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:text=""
      android:id="@+id/textView" />
  </ScrollView>

  <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Show"
  android:id="@+id/buttonShow"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonUpdate"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonUpdate" />

  <EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
  android:hint="Enter new phone"
  android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView" />
  ```
- MainActivity.java

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  SQLiteDatabase db;
  TextView txtMsg;
  Button btnInsert;
  Button btnDelete;
  Button btnUpdate;
  Button btnShow;
  EditText edtID;
  EditText edtName;
  EditText edtPhone;

  // id
  static int id = 0;

  // Friends list
  List<Friend> friendList;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //initializeTable();
      resetTable();
      getWidgets();
  }

  private void resetTable() {
      Friend.deleteAll(Friend.class);
  }

  // Get friend list
  private List<Friend> getFriendList()
  {
      return Friend.listAll(Friend.class);
  }

  // Show to textView
  private void show()
  {
      txtMsg.setText("");
      friendList = getFriendList();
      txtMsg.append("[ID, Name, Phone]");
      for (int i = 0;  i < friendList.size(); i++)
      {
          txtMsg.append("\n[" + friendList.get(i).recID + ", " +
          friendList.get(i).name + ", " + friendList.get(i).phone + "]");
      }
  }

  private void getWidgets() {
      txtMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
      edtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
      edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
      edtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
      btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInsert);
      btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
      btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
      btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);
      btnInsert.setOnClickListener(this);
      btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
      btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
      btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

  // insert
  private void insert()
  {
      txtMsg.setText("");
      try
      {
          Friend f = new Friend(++id, edtName.getText().toString(),   edtPhone.getText().toString());
          f.save();
          txtMsg.setText("Insert successfully");
          txtMsg.append(f.toString());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          txtMsg.setText(e.toString());
      }
  }

  // delete
  private void delete()
  {
      txtMsg.setText("");
      int pos = -1;
      try
      {
          try
          {
              pos = Integer.parseInt(edtID.getText().toString());
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              txtMsg.setText(e.toString());
          }

          Friend f = Friend.findById(Friend.class, pos);
          f.delete();
          txtMsg.setText("Delete successfully");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          txtMsg.setText(e.toString());
      } 
  }

  // update
  private void update()
  {
      txtMsg.setText("");
      long pos = -1;
      try {
          try
          {
              pos = Long.parseLong(edtID.getText().toString());
               Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              txtMsg.setText(e.toString());
          }

          Friend f = SugarRecord.findById(Friend.class, pos);
          f.name = edtName.getText().toString();
          f.phone = edtPhone.getText().toString();
          f.save();
          txtMsg.setText("Update successfully");
          txtMsg.append(f.toString());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          txtMsg.setText(e.toString());
      }
  }


  // Button click
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      if (view.getId() == btnShow.getId()) {
          show();
      } else if (view.getId() == btnInsert.getId()) {
          insert();
      } else if (view.getId() == btnUpdate.getId()) {
          update();
      } else if (view.getId() == btnDelete.getId()) {
          delete();
      }
  }
  ```
- The problem is that when I try to update, I got error. For example, I insert 6 rows like below

[image]

now I update row number 2, error here!

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
Friend f = SugarRecord.findById(Friend.class, pos);
```

to:

```
Friend f = Friend.findById(Friend.class, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here I think:
`SugarRecord.findById(Friend.class, pos);` must be `Friend.findById(Friend.class, pos);`.

The problem is indicates that a variable that it indexes to an object is " without object " so try with Friend.findById.